# How to split line of text (first half bold, second half not bold) when creating document using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Instead of:

`doc.appendparagraph();`

how do you add a line of text to your document without it returning to the next line?

I'm trying to break up a line of text and bold the first half the sentence with `.setAttributes(bold);`

bold which I've defined using....

`var boldpl = {};`
`boldpl[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;`.

Thank you.

I've figured out how to do this in a roundabout way using a merge feature, but how do you go about adding a new line instead of a new paragraph?  There is no doc.appendText(); feature is there?

Also is there an easy way to make my document single spaced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've asked a lot of different questions there!

> Given an existing paragraph, how can some portion of it be rendered in
>   **bold** while the rest remains normal?

A [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) contains a [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body.html), which can contain [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph)s, each of which can contain other elements, including Text. You can get that Text either as a string - which you can't do much with - or as a [Text Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text). Here's an example of using the [`Text.setBold()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold%28Integer,Integer,Boolean%29) method to change just some text in a paragraph to bold:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var firstParagraph = body.getParagraphs()[0];
textElement = firstParagraph.editAsText();

textElement.setBold(0,6,true); // Set the 0th to 6th characters bold
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Text.setAttributes()` method with your custom attribute `boldpl`:

```
textElement.setAttributes(0,6, boldpl)
```

Starting with that building block, you could do things like:

- Apply bold from the start of a paragraph until the first occurrence of a colon (`:`).
- Apply bold to the first few words.
- ...or even apply bold to the first half!

  ```
  textElement.setBold(0,
                      Math.floor((textElement.getText().length)/2),
                      true);
  ```

> There is no doc.appendText(); feature is there?

No... but there is a [`Paragraph.appendText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#appendText%28String%29) method.

> Also is there an easy way to make my document single spaced?

You can control the line spacing of text within paragraphs, by setting attributes on individual paragraphs. See [`Paragraph.setLineSpacing()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setLineSpacing%28Number%29). Here's a function that sets every paragraph in your document to single-spacing:

```
function singleSpace() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraphs = bodyElement.getParagraphs();

  // Set each paragraph to single-spaced
  paragraphs.forEach( function( paragraph ) {
    paragraph.setLineSpacing( 1.0 );
  });
}
```

Comment: This answer is beautiful.

Comment: @Mogsdad, great explanation - Could you elaborate on how you would achieve part of y our answer above "Apply bold from the start of a paragraph until the first occurrence of a colon (:)." I am trying to apply this on my code but can't seem to be able to isolate the :